# How do I prevent a continuous loop from ending

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script which calls a php script every 10 minutes thats performs some maintenance. Every once in a while this php script terminates while it's running and when this happens the bash script exits.

I'd like to make it so the bash script keeps on looping even if the php script falters. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been searching for a while but I can't seem to find the answer, maybe I'm not using the right search terms.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e    
while :    
do    
    /usr/bin/php /path/to/maintenance/script.php
    sleep 600    
done
```

Comment: Would you consider setting up a chron job to handle this instead?

Comment: cron is the correct way, but also, your `while` loop, don't you set some condition? I mean it loop infinitely in your code sample above.

Comment: @rjz: I don't want to use cron for this since the time the php script takes to run is variable and I don't want to deal with a pid file.

Comment: @Jasonw: The point of the script is so it runs continuously.

Comment: It should not exit the loop even when it is in error. May be you should describe what error it is.

Comment: Indeed, the loop won't exit unless you've set `-e` or enabled a `trap` on `ERR` or similar (which you haven't, above).  Of course something external could kill the script, but it seems more likely that the php code is getting stuck and just sitting around forever, so that you never get to the `sleep` command.

Comment: @torek: It seems when I slimmed down the actual script for the example above I removed a `set -e` line (I updated the question to reflect this). Thanks for heads up on that, if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The:

```
set -e
```

line sets the shell's "exit on error" flag, which tells it that if a program it runs exits with a non-zero status, the shell should also exit:

```
set -e
false
echo if this prints, your shell is not honoring "set -e"
```

There are exceptions for programs whose status is being tested, of course, so that:

```
set -e
if prog; then
    echo program succeeded
else
    echo program failed
fi
echo this will still print
```

will work correctly (one or or the other echo will occur, and then the last one will as well).

Back in the Dim Time, when `/bin/sh` was non-POSIX and was written in Bournegol, there was a bug in some versions of `sh` that broke `||` expressions:

```
set -e
false || true
echo if this prints, your shell is OK
```

(The logic bug applied to `&&` expressions internally as well, but was harmless there, since `false && anything` is itself false which means the whole expression fails anyway!)  Ever since then, I've been wary of "-e".

Answer (score 2):

Rjz's comment is correct, you should use `cron`.  To do that, run `crontab -e` and add this line:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/maintenance/script.php
```

If it's set up properly, `cron` will email you any output (including error messages).